How to disable this "What's new" popup every time I open nvim?
Every time I open nvim with LazyVim, it shows a popup with "What's new" as the title. How to disable it ?


You're using LazyVim with your Neovim installation. By default, this setup displays a "News" popup when nvim starts.
LazyVim reads news from NEWS.md file and displays it, see its code in https://github.com/LazyVim/LazyVim/blob/main/lua/lazyvim/util/news.lua
You can disable it in your configuration with news = { lazyvim = false } (true in the default configuration) in lua/lazyvim/config/init.lua file.
